# Raspberry install Application on Windows PC at boot

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, lync, arduino

I am not sure if this es even possible or if I just was searching for the wrong term.

The Goal is that a Raspberry (or Arduino) controls some LEDs. Which of the LEDs is turned on will be sent by a C# Application running on the Windows Computer. The OS of the Windows Computer often gets reinstalled or the whole HD is beeing changed, so the goal is not having to reinstall the software everytime manually. The Raspberry always stays connected to the Computer over USB. Is there a way to install the software from a Raspberry (or even Arduino) on the Computer at boot or do you have any other idea how you would approach this?

An other way would be to directly read the LyncClient, which is "running" on the Windows Computer, Data from the Raspberry itself (= Skype for Buisness Availability), but I dont think this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Cool name there Crack Head 420!! Lol

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT your name isn't bad either xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your windows PC access a network drive that is constantly on.  That way you can always save your code on the network drive, and not have to keep anything on the PC itself.

Or you could have your code on a USB flash drive, with auto run configured

Comment: There was no way to make a workaround, I couldnt get the raspberry to somehow get access directly to the Windows PC (via USB) or upload the exe to the Computer. I then made an autorun USB stick and made the program on the arduino, which controls the leds, notice if theres no program running on the PC. Thank you alot :)